# How can verify the result $v^Tx=0, x$ is eigenvector for A?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

$A=UV^T  $    ,

$U = [u_1, u_2,\dots ,u_n]^T$ and  $V= [v_1,v_2\dots,v_n]^T$

Let
$V^TX=0 , X $ is eigenvector for A .

(1) how can I verify it and solve the eigenvalue? and

(2) 
if $\det(I+A)=\operatorname{Tr}(A)+1$,  find  the other eigenvalue, different  from  (1)

I cannot get it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A\cdot X=(U\cdot V^T)\cdot X=U\cdot(V^T\cdot X)=U\cdot 0=0 = 0X$$
Do you see what the eigenvalue is now?

Comment: hmm... I can't follow you..

Comment: @matthew I've edited the question a bit, is it better? If not, what is giving you trouble?

Comment: omg what have I done for hours...... thank you. by the way , Can I find another eigenvalue ? If that $ det(I+A)= Tr(A)+1$?

Comment: You can write any matrix as a product like this, so it's impossible to find anything without additional conditions.